# How do I participate in chat?

Tags: support, chat

I have enough reputation to participate in chat, and I have a feeling that there's a button somewhere, but I just can't find anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On desktop, you can click on the Stack Exchange button, and then click 'chat':

[image: Stack Exchange dropdown]

The main gaming chat room is [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge).

Comment: Our main room is [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), feel free to join.

Comment: @arda Added thanks :).